# VHDL std logic vector increment

Tags: vhdl, fpga, stdvector

I have received a code where the coder has somehow written

```
a <= a + 1
```

Where `a` is `std_logic_vector (15 downto 0)`. Is this correct? and if so, how does this arithmetic operation work?

Comment: Please could you list the packages used by the code (in its _context clause_)?

Comment: numeric_std_unsigned will allow arithmatic with std_logic_vector. The non-standard std_logic_unsigned/signed will also allow it. They are pretty commonly used.